# ¤ symbol appearing instead of $ in the textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

It was an already written code, which is suddenly popping up the unknown currency symbol. This works fine when the culture is en-IN, but displays ¤ when the culture is en-US.

The following is the converter which I call from corresponding XAML page.

```
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is decimal)
        {
            return String.Format("{0:c}", value);
        }
        else
            return String.Empty;

    }
```

Honestly, I couldn't try anything because it was working in VS 2010, but when it the entire product is shifted to VS 2015, this error pops. But I don't think Visual Studio has anything to do with it.

Comment: Also read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol?view=netframework-4.8 (search in it for `"¤`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply the culture object to the string.Format method that takes a format provider:

```
string.Format(culture, "{0:C}", value);
```

The culture will act as a format provider and then this should work in all languages.